# Django 1.11 annotation GROUP BY is wrong

Tags: django, group-by, subquery

With model relations like this

```
Risk <-- RiskGroup --> Group
```

I am trying to achieve a query resembling this

```
SELECT risk.id,
       (
         SELECT array_agg(bg.name) as names
         FROM hazards_riskgroup rgroup
                JOIN (SELECT * FROM base_group ORDER BY name) as bg
                     on rgroup.group_id = bg.id
         WHERE risk_id = risk.id
         GROUP BY risk_id
         ORDER BY risk_id
       ) AS conf
FROM hazards_risk risk
ORDER BY conf NULLS LAST
;
```

And I have gotten as far as

```
group_names = (
    RiskGroup.objects
    .filter(risk_id=OuterRef('pk'))
    .annotate(names=ArrayAgg('group__name'))
    .order_by()
    .order_by("group__name")
    .values('names')
)
qs = Risk.objects.annotate(
    conf=Subquery(group_names)
).order_by(F('conf').asc(nulls_last=True))
```

But that wil produce something along the lines of this query

```
SELECT risk.id,
       (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(U2."name") AS "names"
        FROM "hazards_riskgroup" U0
               INNER JOIN "base_group" U2 ON (U0."group_id" = U2."id")
        WHERE U0."risk_id" = (risk.id)
        GROUP BY U0."id", U2."name"
        ORDER BY U2."name" ASC) AS "conf"
FROM hazards_risk risk
ORDER BY conf NULLS LAST
```

Notice that the generated `GROUP BY` becomes `GROUP BY U0."id", U2."name"`, where I want just `GROUP BY U2."name"`.

Best I've been able to gather, is that it is related to some default ordering on models, but as you can tell, I've already accounted for that by inserting `.order_by()`.

So I'm a little lost. I tried annotating with Raw sql instead, but in that case, I can't seem to be able to reference `risk.id` which is important to get the right group names for each risk.

Comment: No information about your models and their relationships. It's difficult to guess